# How hard to hack and read iOS app bundle data from binary?

Tags: ios, security, bundle, data-integrity

I'm working on an app that has a built-in database (initially stored in JSON files).  Currently this data is not encrypted.

How hard is it for a hacker to get access to this internal app data after downloading from App Store?

Comment: If the device is jailbroken, trivial. If you encrypt it, reverse engineering your app to get the key and decrypting it will be slightly more difficult, but not a significant barrier. If there were a reliable technique to protect data from the owner of a jailbroken device, Apple would use that technique to prevent jailbreaking. If you send data to a user's device, they can read that data if they have an incentive to.

Comment: Even if the device isn't jailbroken it is very easy to get the ipa off the device onto a computer and then it is just a zip file you can open

Comment: @RobNapier Does what Paulw11 says mean that the data is readable after all, meaning that what you wrote might be incorrect?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "might be incorrect." Paul's just saying there's an even easier way to extract the IPA (I'm not aware of a currently-working way to do that since Apple got rid of iTunes without a jailbroken phone, but he's generally pretty smart about these things, and it's not something I've tried to do in a few years). But in any case, I'm saying "pretty easy" and Paul is saying "even easier than that." I'm also saying, with a jailbroken phone, undoing any encryption you apply is likely pretty easy. Hopefully that answers the question.